# Removing Select Options from Appended Select Menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Good morning Stack Overflow,

This will be my first question and I am still learning coding, so please forgive me if I'm ever being naive.

I am currently working on a modal that the user is shown when they're trying to pick quantities of a certain product from a warehouse that has been stored in multiple locations.

The user is given a requested quantity and the drop down menu shows each of the possible locations that they can retrieve an item from. The user will then select the location using the select menu and then adjust the slider with the amount they want to take from that location.

If the user wants to split the requested amount across multiple locations however, they will click the "Pick Another Location" button and another row containing the select menu will appear directly underneath. The user will be able to do this until the total picked has reached the Quantity Requested or until they run out of locations to pick from. My problem is, I am trying to remove the location the user selected prior to clicking the "Pick Another Location" button.

[image]

As you can see the same location appears again in the appended menu. I would like to have it so it doesn't. Its turning out to be quite difficult for me because each location picker has a unique ID that is created with a variable and I find it difficult to implement that into any types of condition usually.

I had a similar issue with the Quantity slider, as I was trying to treat each slider individually, but also contribute as a collective. Anyway, starting to get off topic and ramble.

I will show below the code which I feel may help...

Initial creation and variables declared:

```
//Multiple Location PopUp Function
jQuery.LocPick = function LocPick(id){
//Function Post
$.post(base_url+"ts/TestedQtyMultiLoc/", { 
                                ID: id,
                                BatchID: $("#BatchID").val()},

//Calling variables to be displayed within the PopUp                                
function(data){
QtyReq = data.item.QtyRequested;
var code= data.item.ItemCode;
rowCount = $('#AddLocationPicker tr').length;
loc='';
$.each(data.Locations, function(i, value) {loc +='<option value="'+ value.Location + '">' + value.Location + ' -- Qty: ' +value.Qty +'</option>';
})
Picker=0;
```

This is the code for the HTML contents of my modal:

```
//PopUp Contents
$("#dialog-ProcessConfirm").html('<p>'+code+' has multiple locations<br><br>Please confirm which locations the item is to be picked from before continuing.</p><p><table id="AddLocationPicker"><tr><td></td><td>Location</td><td>Qty Picked</td></tr><tr id="' + Picker +'"><td></td><td><select class="selectbox" id="LocationPickerSelect'+ Picker +'"><option value="0">Please select a location'+loc+'</option></select></td><td><input class= "QtyPicker" id="AddLocQtyPick'+ Picker +'"type="number" min="1" max='+QtyReq+' value="1" onkeydown="return false"></td></tr></table><table><td></td><td>Quantity Requested:</td><td>'+QtyReq+'</td></table><table><td></td><td><input type="text" name="LocErr" id="LocErr" maxlength="50" size="50" tabstop="false" readonly="true" style="border:0px;color:#FF0000;" value=""><input type="text" name="QtyErr" id="QtyErr" maxlength="50" size="50" tabstop="false" readonly="true" style="border:0px;color:#FF0000;" value=""></td></table></p>');
}, "json");
```

The "Pick Another Location Button":

```
//Buttons for the PopUp

buttons: { 

'Pick Another Location': function() { //Button to allow user to add another location to pick from

$('#AddLocQtyPick'+Picker).prop ('disabled', true); //Disables the current selection, so that it cannot be edited

$('#LocationPickerSelect'+ Picker).prop ('disabled', true);  //Disables the current selection, so that it cannot be edited

Picker++; //Adds Unique Number to the ID of the input fields

//For Loop that helps to total up the quantities being selected in each picker
total=0;
for (i = 0; i<Picker; i++) {
total= total + $('#AddLocQtyPick'+i).val() * 1.0;
}

QtyReqTot= QtyReq - total; //Variable decides max value of pick on appends using previous selection
```

What gets appended:

```
//The Location/Quantity Picker that gets appended
var appendTxt = '<tr id="' + Picker + '"><td></td><td><select class= "selectbox" id="LocationPickerSelect'+ Picker +'"><option value="0">Please select a location'+loc+'</option></select></td><td><input class= "QtyPicker" id="AddLocQtyPick'+ Picker +'" type="number" min="1" max='+QtyReqTot+' value="1" onkeydown="return false"></td></tr>';
```

I didn't know if I could use the same sort of technique in using For Loops to use with the incrementing IDS that the Location Picker has, like I did with the Quantity slider as I've seen some examples that suggest this whilst others have said to never use loops in this situation.

My main issue boils down to how I can select an option in one unique menu and remove that option from another unique menu that has the same options.

I'll thank you now for any input/advice received and for patience in my abilities!

**EDIT: Problem Solved**

The problem I was having did involve trying to take the unique ID's into consideration when writing my syntax. Confirmation for the use of a for loop allowed me to compare with my previous loop I created when totalling the picker quantities.

```
//For Loop that removes previously selected locations from the append
for (i = 0; i<Picker; i++) {
LocSelect= $('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val();
$('#LocationPickerSelect'+Picker+' option[value="'+LocSelect+'"]').remove();
}
```

Comment: You are making really lot to take in for users here. Make it simple and post again. You will get answer for sure. Better luck next time.

Comment: Hi, If I am not wrong you want to delete the option from select if the same option is selected above? Please correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: Thank you for the advice @divy3993 , I shall take that into account if I ask another question. I was going to edit this one but have since then figured out how to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this question @AnandGhaywankar , I have since figured out how to solve my problem. You were right in your assumption, I did want the option that was previously selected to be deleted from the appended selection menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having did involve trying to take the unique ID's into consideration when writing my syntax. Confirmation for the use of a for loop allowed me to compare with my previous loop I created when totalling the picker quantities.

```
//For Loop that removes previously selected locations from the append
for (i = 0; i<Picker; i++) {
LocSelect= $('#LocationPickerSelect'+i).val();
$('#LocationPickerSelect'+Picker+' option[value="'+LocSelect+'"]').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to go with following approach:

Instead of simply adding all the `<option>` to each select box like below:

```
$.each(data.Locations, function(i, value) {loc +='<option value="'+ value.Location + '">' + value.Location + ' -- Qty: ' +value.Qty +'</option>';
})
```

Go for following code which check; which all `<option>` are already been selected by end user. And adds only those which are unused previously.

```
var prevSelectedLoc = [];
if(Picker > 0)
{
    for(i=0;i<Picker;i++)
    {
        prevSelectedLoc.push($("select#LocationPickerSelect"+i).val());
    }
}
$.each(data.Locations, function(i, value) {
    if($.inArray(value.Location,prevSelectedLoc) == -1)
    {
        //if current option has not been previously selected then only add it to current select box
        loc +='<option value="'+ value.Location + '">' + value.Location + ' -- Qty: ' +value.Qty +'</option>';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @vijayP , it was intriguing to me! However, I have since solved the problem, I marked your answer as useful, as it confirmed my thinking in that I should use a for loop, but at the moment my rep is to low for it to have an affect!